# Method of steepest descent approximate the integral $I(\lambda )=\int\limits_{1}^{\infty }\left ( \frac{\ln x}{x} \right )^{\lambda }dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, approximation, approximate-integration

At $\lambda \to \infty $ Method of steepest descent approximate the integral
$$I(\lambda )=\int\limits_{1}^{\infty }\left ( \frac{\ln x}{x} \right )^{\lambda }dx$$

**My attempt:**

The method itself and the general formula

$$I(\lambda) = \int\limits_a^b f(x) e^{\lambda S(x)} \, dx, \quad \lambda \to \infty.$$

где $f(x)$ и $S(x)$ - некоторые функции.

I have not been able to apply this method to my integral. At $x>e$ the function decreases, and decreases more rapidly as $\lambda$ increases. Consequently, most of the contribution to the integral at $\lambda \to \infty$ comes from values of $x$ close to $e$. In the limit at $\lambda \to \infty$ the integral will tend to zero, i.e.

$$I(\lambda )=\int\limits_{1}^{\infty }\left ( \frac{\ln x}{x} \right )^{\lambda }dx \to 0, \quad \lambda \to \infty$$

This is my reasoning, but I have not been able to calculate an approximate integral. Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral can be studied with [Laplace's method](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3#iii). One has

$$
I = \int_1^{\infty}\left(\frac{\ln x}{x} \right)^{\lambda} dx = \int_1^{\infty} \exp\left(-\lambda \left(\ln x -\ln \ln x\right)\right)dx, \quad \lambda \rightarrow \infty
$$

Let $p(x) = \ln x -\ln \ln x$, a minimum occurs around $x=e$ and Taylor expanding around this point, one has

$$
p(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{2e^2} (x-e)^2 - \frac{5}{6e^3}(x-e)^3 +...
$$

Split the integral into two parts, the first one  from $1$ to $e$ ($I_1$) and the second from $e$ to infinity ($I_2$). For the second integral, one may identify from the link the parameters $p(a) = 1,P=(2e^2)^{-1},\mu=2,Q=1,\lambda=1$, at the point $a=e$, which gives the dominating term

$$
I_2 = \int_1^{\infty}\left(\frac{\ln x}{x} \right)^{\lambda} dx \sim \frac{Q}{\mu}\Gamma\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu} \right) \frac{e^{-\lambda p(a)}}{(Px)^{\lambda/\mu}} = e\sqrt{\frac{{\pi}}{2}} \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda^{1/2}}
$$

One may similarly show that $I_1 = I_2$ which then gives

$$
I = \int_1^{\infty}\left(\frac{\ln x}{x} \right)^{\lambda} dx \sim \sqrt{2\pi}e\lambda^{-1/2}e^{-\lambda}, \quad \lambda \rightarrow \infty
$$

to leading order. From the same link, it is shown how to include additional terms if necessary.

Comment: A nice solution. But we can also notice that 
$$I(\lambda )=\int\limits_{1}^{\infty }\left ( \frac{\ln x}{x} \right )^{\lambda }dx\overset{x=e^t}{=}\int_0^\infty e^{-t(\lambda-1)}t^\lambda dt=\frac{\Gamma(\lambda+1)}{(\lambda-1)^{1+\lambda}}$$

Comment: Thanks @Svyatoslav! As the question was so heavily focused on an asymptotic expansion, I completely overlooked any exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the change of variables from $x$ to $t$ via $x = {\rm e}^{{\rm e}^t }$ to obtain
$$
I(\lambda ) = \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{{\rm e}^t  + t}{\rm e}^{ \lambda (t-{\rm e}^t)}  {\rm d}t}  = {\rm e}^{ - \lambda } \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{{\rm e}^t  + t}{\rm e}^{ \lambda (1-t-{\rm e}^t)}  {\rm d}t} .
$$
Now the sole maximum of $1-t-{\rm e}^t$ is at $t=0$. Hence, by the method of Laplace,
$$
I(\lambda ) = {\rm e}^{ - \lambda } \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{{\rm e}^t  + t}{\rm e}^{ - \lambda ({\rm e}^t  - t - 1)}  {\rm d}t}  \sim {\rm e}^{ - \lambda } {\rm e}\sqrt {\frac{{2\pi }}{\lambda }}  = \sqrt {2\pi }  \lambda ^{ - 1/2} {\rm e}^{1 - \lambda } 
$$
as $\lambda\to +\infty$.