# In the limit $\lambda \to \infty $ approximate the integral $I(\lambda )=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-x^2}(\cosh x)^{\lambda }dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, approximation, approximate-integration

With the help of the previous answer ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4704224/method-of-steepest-descent-approximate-the-integral-i-lambda-int-limits-1/4704261#4704261)) I decided to do the same with this integral

In the limit $\lambda \to \infty $ approximate the integral
$$I(\lambda )=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-x^2}(\cosh x)^{\lambda }dx$$

My attempt:

Substitute $\cosh x = e^{x} + e^{-x}$
$$I(\lambda )=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-x^2}\left(e^{x} + e^{-x}\right)^{\lambda }dx=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-x^2}e^{\lambda x}dx + \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-x^2}e^{-\lambda x}dx$$

$$I(\lambda )=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-x^2}(\cosh x)^{\lambda }dx \approx 2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}e^{\lambda}, \quad \lambda \rightarrow \infty$$

Did I apply this method correctly? Did I find the correct approximate value?

Comment: $(e^x + e^{-x})^\lambda \neq e^{\lambda x} + e^{-\lambda x}$

Comment: Actually, $\cosh x=\color{red}{\frac12}(e^x+e^{-x})$. Replacing $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ with $2\int_0^\infty$ might help.

Comment: Yes, of course $(e^x + e^{-x})^\lambda \neq e^{\lambda x} + e^{-\lambda x}$, I was hasty. But if correctly decomposed through exponents, can this method be applied?

Comment: $(\cosh(x))^\lambda\leq\cosh(\lambda x)$ by Jensen's inequality.

Comment: $I(\lambda )=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-x^2}(\cosh x)^{\lambda }dx\leq =\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-x^2}\cosh \lambda xdx$ ?

Comment: @Partim: For $\lambda\geq1$, yes indeed. This yields $I(\lambda)=O(e^{\lambda^2/4})$ as $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$, however may not be the *optimal* rate of growth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

\begin{align*}
I(\lambda)
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}(\cosh x)^{\lambda} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2^{1-\lambda} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2+\lambda x}(1 + e^{-2x})^{\lambda} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= e^{\lambda^2/4} 2^{1-\lambda} \int_{-\lambda/2}^{\infty} e^{-y^2}(1 + e^{-2y-\lambda})^{\lambda} \, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{align*}

Using this and invoking dominated convergence theorem, it is easy to check that

$$ I(\lambda) \sim e^{\lambda^2/4}2^{1-\lambda}\sqrt{\pi} $$

as $\lambda \to \infty$. Furthermore, it is possible to show that the relative error of this asymptotic formula,

$$ \left| \frac{I(\lambda)}{e^{\lambda/4}2^{1-\lambda}\sqrt{\pi}} - 1 \right|, $$

decays exponentially fast as $\lambda \to \infty$:

[image: Plot of relative error]

Comment: How are you applying dominated convergence in $\int^\infty_{-\lambda/2}e^{-y^2}(1+e^{-(2y+\lambda)})\,dy\xrightarrow{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\pi}$?

Comment: @OliverDíaz, Noting that $$e^{-y^2}(1+e^{-2y-\lambda})^{\lambda}\leq\begin{cases}e^{-y^2}(1+e^{-\lambda/2})^{\lambda},&y\in[-\frac{\lambda}{4},\infty)\\e^{-y^2/2}e^{-\lambda^2/32}2^{\lambda},&y\in[-\frac{\lambda}{2},-\frac{\lambda}{4}]\end{cases}$$ we can obtain a bound of the form $Ce^{-y^2/2}$ for some absolute constant $C>0$. However, I now think it is better to split the integral into two parts, one contributing to $\sqrt{\pi}$ and the other vanishingly small, and estimate them separately.